# How to update a "one to many" relation in Laravel? (can't find it in the docs)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Tickets')

    }
}

class Tickets extends Eloquent {

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('User')

    }
}


//and how to update a Ticket that belongs To User?


// and this dosen't work...Who can tell me the reason ,thanks !
$ticket = User::find(1)->tickets()->where('type','sometype')->get();
$ticket.update(array('status'   =>    0));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update()` query is documented quite plainly in the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#updates):

```
User::find(1)->tickets()->where('type','sometype')->update(array('status' => 0));
```

I suspect the issue you're having is that the [get()` query](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects) is returning *multiple* records. In order for your query to work, you'll need to treat the returned value as a collection if records, then iterate and operate on each record individually.

```
$tickets = User::find(1)->tickets()->where('type','sometype')->get();
foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    $ticket->update(array('status' => 0));
}
```

Note that the correct syntax for invoking an Eloquent method requires a preceding arrow `->` – **not** a dot (`.`).

```
$record.update(array('foo' => 'bar'));   # Incorrect
$record->update(array('foo' => 'bar')); # CORRECT!
```

**UPDATE**:

Model names should always be *singular*, **not** *plural*. Therefore, the `Ticket` model should be defined as follows:

```
class Ticket extends Eloquent { // `Ticket`, not `Tickets`
    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongTo('User')

    }
}
```

Comment: I used to write C#..:P

Comment: I've test your code...but the result is: "all the record in the ticket table were updated,But in the table 'ticket' ,the field 'type' was unique...what's the wrong?

Comment: @Daniel.Woo, clearly, there is no `type` field on the `Ticket`. Any chance that attribute might be named something else? Also, see my update for clarification on naming associations.

Comment: and I print the sql,I find the where condition was "where userid='xxx'",and I expect is "where userid='xxx' and ticketid='xxx'"   but I don't know how to fixed it ...

Comment: Can you please update your question with the _precise_ error code you are receiving? Also, did you rename your model to be singular, and not  plural?

Comment: I solved,     $ticket = User::find(1)->tickets()->where('type','sometype')->get(); $ticket->status = 'xxx';User::find(1)->tickets()->where('type','sometype')->update($ticket->toArray());   this works!

Comment: @Daniel.Woo, I've verified that my solution works – as apparently at least one upvoter has as well. If this answer has helped resolve your issue, please consider accepting it as correct.

Comment: I'm confused that I can't find "the update method"in the Official Doc

Comment: @Daniel.Woo, did you read my answer? [It's right here](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#updates).

Comment: I've tset your code "$ticket->update(array('status' => 0));"does not run correctly...which generate sql"where ticketid ='xxx',not where ticketid='xxx' AND 'userid' == 'xxx'";

Comment: @Daniel.Woo, this is perhaps because your model declaration is not correctly spelled. At any rate, it seems that you have a functional answer – one that is either identical to this answer, or heavily derived from it – so I won't be following up with any commentary.